# Get file's absolute path SharepointOnline

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I need to get the absolute path of a file within a document library.
Doing some research i figured out that i cannot do that directly by code without querying Sharepoint using CSOM.

Which is the recommended/correct way?

1)

```
context.Load(file, f => f.ListItemAllFields["FileRef"]);
```

2)

Using File.LinkingUrl?

UPDATE

Something like this?

```
            List docLib = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(doclibrary);

            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = @"<View>
                                <Query>
                                    <Where>
                                        <Eq>
                                            <FieldRef Name='Name'/>
                                            <Value Type='Text'>" +versionId+ @"</Value>
                                        </Eq>
                                    </Where>
                                    <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
                                </Query>
                            </View>";

            ListItemCollection collListItems = docLib.GetItems(query);

            context.Load(docLib);
            context.Load(collListItems, items => items.Include(
                item => item["FileRef"],
                item => item["FileLeafRef"],
                item => item["EncodedAbsUrl"]
            ));

            context.ExecuteQuery();

            ListItem listItem = collListItems[0];

            fileAbsPath = (string)listItem["EncodedAbsUrl"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try this.

```
var linkUrl=(stirng)file.item["EncodedAbsUrl"];
```